# chown only for directory ntfs-3g

Tags: mount, ntfs, directory

I just want to move my default mysql (installed by LAMP) directory to NTFS-3G partition, so it was the same I use on Windows. I've already done this with htdocs.

There comes my question: I mount -o bind the folder of /opt/lampp/var/mysql to /media/Dane/mysql but to work properly it has to be posessed by mysql user of mysql group. I mount ntfs-3g partition as root at boot (in /etc/fstab). The only thing I want is to chown only one directory on Dane partition. How do I do so? I don't want to change the whole partition's owner.

Answer (score 0):

First, I highly advise against using ntfs on linux this way.

Second, you can not change ownership or permissions with `mount --bind`

You can try mounting the partition with the permissions option, then the usual commands `chown` and `chmod` should work.

If that does not work, see https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#7

Comment: I'm not using mount -o bind to mount, but to redirect /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ to /media/Dane/mysql/.
Also, I've tried mounting with permissions, but I still can't change the owner of the directory.

Comment: See the link I gave you for user mapping on ntfs partitions. ntfs is not a linux native file system, so if you insist on using it you will have to manually configure ownership and permissions. I again advise you to use a linux native file system.

Comment: I don't understand it at all, but as far as one isn't able to change any NTFS dir ownership, I have to give another method a try.

Comment: I do not know how else to tell you this, but ntfs is not a linux native file system and as such does not support linux ownership and permissions the way you envision. I have already advised you use a linux native file system for exactly these reasons.